# Best practices: Is it vital that 'http:' is put at the beginning of html links?

Tags: html

I have been creating links like so, that work...

```
<a href="//stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>
```

But I am wondering if by removing the 'http' part of the link, does it affect the links in different browsers or have an affect on how search engine robots pick up the links.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not vital (unless you need IE6 support, see below).  Omitting it can be useful at times.
http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

IE6 does have problems with it, see here: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/

Answer (score 3):

It is vital to put `http:` at the start *if* you want to use specifically the http: protocol and not https:. The very idea of URLs starting with `//` is that they use the protocol of the page in which they appear. This is often useful when using both protocols (e.g., in an e-commerce system, you could use http: for search and information operations but then switch to https: when starting actual commercial transaction).

There’s a risk with `//` URLs though: if a page has been saved locally, all such URLs fails when the saved copy is used (unless the program used for saving the page was clever enough to modify the URLs – it probably wasn’t).